# Find Facebook person via FQL starting with Twitter Handle

Tags: twitter, facebook-fql

I am wanting to find a user's Facebook page starting with their Twitter Name.

Is this possible to query using FQL?

I realize that only users who have set their Twitter name in FB will be returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on some quick reading, and working with it, my initial instinct is that it probably isn't possible.  Twitter is an external app to Facebook. Facebook only stores information they have on their site and so that is all that is accessible via FQL.

The documentation is here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

There might be some way to cross reference the two, but not using FQL.